# Kivy image not showing

Tags: python, kivy

Im working on a basic app using python and kivy and im trying to import an image which I'm basically going to use as a splash screen of sorts but for some reason I couldn't get it to work so I created a .py file and wrote some very simple code to try to get it to work:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (360, 640)

class ImageTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        label = Label(source="image.jpg")
        return label

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ImageTestApp().run()
```

The image is in the same directory of the .py file and the name of the image is exactly the same, I even made the window size the same as the image size and tried .PNG but nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label does not have an attribute called source. You should change Label to Image, and it will works. Please refer to example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (360, 640)


class ImageTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Image(source="image.jpg")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ImageTestApp().run()
```

### Output

[image]